# A semantic question about αὐτόματος

Tags: etymology, greek, meaning

Here is a question related to [the one](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4771/about-%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%82) I asked about an hour ago:

As an adjective, the main meaning of αὐτόματος is *self-willed*, but as a noun, it primarily means *accident* or *chance*, according to [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B1%E1%BD%90%CF%84%CF%8C%CE%BC%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%BF%CF%82).

But something that is self-willed seems to be the opposite of something that is accidental, isn't it? If so, is this word similar to [φάρμακον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%86%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%BC%CE%B1%CE%BA%CE%BF%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek), which means both a healing drug and poison, a gathering of contraries?

Comment: I think the clue is in the word Automata. The Byzantine toys which seemed to have a mind were definitely *things,* hence the Greek neuter plural (or singular automaton).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [LSJ entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dau)to%2Fmatos) sheds some light on the semantics. αὐτόματος literally or etymologically means "having a mind of one's own". When applied to people,  αὐτόματος means "acting of one's own will"; when applied to things, which don't have minds,  it means something like "acting on its own, without human control or intervention". Something that happens on its own happens "by chance" in the sense that it has not been brought about by any human agency. When you can't control an occurrence, it's an easy step to thinking of it as happening "of itself" or "of its own accord". If the river floods "of its own will", i.e. without the possibility of human control or prediction, it also can be said to flood "at random".